# sql - the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT [qt].[name] , [qz].[user_id] , [ft].[name] 
 FROM [f]  
   INNER JOIN [o] ON [o].[id] = [f].[o_id]
    INNER JOIN [q] as q2 ON [q2].[id] = [o].[q_id]
     INNER JOIN [ft] ON [ft].[id] = [f].[ft_id] 
      INNER JOIN [qt] ON [q].[qt_id] =  [qt].[id] 
       INNER JOIN [qz] ON [q].[id] = [qz].[q_id] 
WHERE exportable = 1
```

This is my query.For some reason I'm getting the  "the multi-part identifier could not be bound" error for lines 6 and 7,but I don't actually know why.Giving a hint would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your Research?  I'm sure you could google this error.

Comment: I have, I even had a script that should've been running but I messed up some things because the main issue was that I had the wrong order,but I changed some other things due to the stuff I read in the answers I found googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in line `ON [q].[id] = [qz].[q_id]`

You created alias on table `q as q2` and you need to refer table using this alias.

```
SELECT [qt].[name] 
      ,[qz].[user_id] 
      ,[ft].[name] 
 FROM [f]  
 JOIN [o] 
   ON [o].[id] = [f].[o_id]
 JOIN [q] as q2       -- alias created, so you need to use it
   ON [q2].[id] = [o].[q_id]
 JOIN [ft] 
   ON [ft].[id] = [f].[ft_id] 
 JOIN [qt] 
   ON [q].[qt_id] =  [qt].[id] 
 JOIN [qz] 
   ON [q2].[id] = [qz].[q_id] 
 WHERE exportable = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The alias `q2` isn't required. If so, you have to use the alias in the last `join` condition.

The problem with the original query was that a table alias defined previously (`[q] as q2`) wasn't being used in the later condition.

It is also a good practice to use the tablename before `exportable` in the `where` clause.

```
   SELECT [qt].[name] , [qz].[user_id] , [ft].[name] 
 FROM [f]  
   INNER JOIN [o] ON [o].[id] = [f].[o_id]
   INNER JOIN [q] ON [q].[id] = [o].[quelle_id]
   INNER JOIN [ft] ON [ft].[id] = [f].[ft_id] 
   INNER JOIN [qt] ON [q].[qt_id] =  [qt].[id] 
   INNER JOIN [qz] ON [q].[id] = [qz].[q_id] 
WHERE exportable = 1
```